# Flutter: WeChat Assets Picker. Change language to English

Tags: flutter, assets, picker, wechat, non-english

I am using flutter [wechat_assets_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker), but the language in select picture/camera screen is in Chinese:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZjLn.png)

Is there anyway to change the language to English?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to just pass EnglishTextDelegate to textDelegate argument

selectedImages = await AssetPicker.pickAssets(context,textDelegate:EnglishTextDelegate() );

Answer (score 1):

The plugin now supports determining which language (if the language is supported) to use by lookup the `Locale` through the widget tree. In summary:

- If your project supports localizations through the widget tree (`Locale` specified in the `WidgetsApp`), the picker will do its own to choose the matching locale.
- If none of the languages you're using are supported by the picker, customize your own by extending `AssetPickerTextDelegate`, then pass through the `AssetPickerConfig.textDelegate` when calling the picker.